# Reverse Email Address Lookup and Email Validation

Tags: database, email, microsoft-excel

What is the best site or tool to do email address validation or a reverse lookup for the name attached to that email. I am working in a database for a company and they need to verify who their leads are and if they are legitimate. Also, is there an extension or plugin for Excel of Google Sheets that would allow this to be done in bulk?

Comment: Hi Cody, I honestly doubt if such a thing exists outside of some government monitoring database. There are too many places for a person to obtain an email account and a multitude of mail forwarding services that exist to allow users to hide their "real" account (e.g., trashmail.com).

Comment: But there must be a way to validate an email no? Like to make sure that the email is still connected to a mail server.

Comment: Sorry, but no. In the old days you could use the finger utility to ping the server's directory, but those days are long gone. Short of actually connecting to the server to send an email, most servers refuse connections. There was way too much abuse connected with spamming and phishing to continuing allowing that access. About the only thing to do is send a message requesting a their confirming reply. I don't know if it's a common practice anymore, but I remember using a catch-all address on my smtp server accepted all messages that didn't match a current user and then trashed them immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there are any tools which do reverse email address lookup. But there surely are tools which can validate bulk leads. One such tool is [Clearout](https://clearout.io), it makes sure that the email is still connected to a mail server and many other things. 
You can download the results in csv format.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of online SaaS tools doing what are you looking for.
It is the tool you are looking for: https://debounce.io/solutions/data-appending-and-enrichment/

You may also check this API: https://debounce.readme.io/reference/data-append